# How can I align paging left or center using Datatables syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to work out how to use the DOM in Datatables to alter the pagination controls, but I am really confused about the syntax for it.  [The syntax is here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html).

I get that `p` is paging, so if I declare `t<"bottom"p>` it will result in the table occurring, then the paging, and that I could reverse that with `t<"top"p>`, but its less clear how I would, for example, float the paging left, or center it.  Is there something I'm missing in regards to the syntax? It doesn't seem to be CSS, so, for example `t<"bottom justify-content-center"p>` does nothing.

Comment: I agree the syntax for this is rather confusing; nearly as bad as Regex :) `its less clear how i would, for example, float the paging left, or center it` for those tasks you'd be better to use CSS.

Comment: To be more clear, apply CSS to the rendered table, not classes in your Datatables markup. Use a wrapper class on a containing element if necessary. If you'd like help with that, please post a simplified snippet of the rendered table.

Comment: Yep, I agree with both previous comments, one trick that I've come to use quite a lot is to use Template Literals in order to check the nesting of the `dom` syntax, that seems to help me, but might cause issues with IE11... other than that you'll (as pointed out by @isherwood), use CSS.